# Azure Linux Virtual Machines Price per Hour, Computation or Running?

Tags: cloud, azure

first of all, I couldn't find a StackExchange site on Cloud Computing. I think this is the most appropriate site, because some of you might be using Azure.

So I just wanted to know:
The Windows Azure Pricing Page shows Linux Virtual Machine Price as $0.013/hr for an extra small VM.

The monthly price comes up to about $10.

Is this price charged as number of hours of computation done on the VM or number of hours of running the VM?

And if I shutdown the VM, will I be charged anything?

Comment: Why do you ask this question here instead of contacting the Azure support? They know for sure.

Comment: This all should be in the service provider documentation. I know it is so in their major competitor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nearly all cloud computing providers charge by **running hour** not *cpu hour*. This is in large part because the constrained resource is not the CPU, rather it's the RAM. An extra-small instance will be charged that $0.013/hr so long as it is running, even if all it is doing is recompiling `apropos` data once a day.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the info, and the reason to why its that way. Thanks. :D